# Displaying 2d array as a map

Tags: c++, arrays, class, object, multidimensional-array

I need a 2d array to be displayed as a map. g_length and and w_width is how long it is starting from x and y point. Need to create a loop that takes width and length of an crop which should be placed on the map.x_crop and y_crop are x and y coordinates where the crop should created. w_width is width and g_length is length or height of the crop located in the class.

```
bool Crop::place(char map[MAPL][MAPW],int x_crop,int y_crop)const{

int y_total =y_crop;
y_total = y_crop + g_length;

for(int x=0; x < MAPW;x++){

    if(x==x_crop){
        for(int b=0; b < w_width;b++){
            if(y_total==y_crop){
                map[x][y_crop] = PlantType.symbol();
                x++;
                y_crop++;
            }else{
                b=w_width;
            }   
        x++;        
        }
    }
}


cout << '\n';
cout << setw(24) << right << "11111111112\n";
cout << setw(24) << right << "12345678901234567890\n";
cout << "  " << setw(21) << setfill('-') << left << '+' << right << '+' << setfill (' ') << endl;



for(int x=0; x < MAPW;x++){
    cout << setw(2) << right << x+1 << "|";
    for(int y=0; y < MAPL;y++){
        cout << map[x][y];

    }
    cout << "|" << endl;
}

cout << "  " << setw(21) << setfill('-') << left << '+' << right << '+' << setfill (' ') << endl;
cout << setw(24) << right << "11111111112\n";
cout << setw(24) << right << "12345678901234567890\n";

return true;}
```

Heres how the out output supposed to look like:

```
            11111111112
   12345678901234567890
  +--------------------+
 1|                    |
 2|                    |
 3|    cc              |
 4|    cc              |
 5|    cc              |
 6|    cc              |
 7|           pppppppp |
 8|           pppppppp |
 9|           pppppppp |
10|                    |
  +--------------------+
            11111111112
   12345678901234567890
```

>

Comment: What is the question ?

Comment: @Jarod42 how should the for loop look like to get the output as provided in the question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not make the loop overly complicated:

```
for (int x = x_crop; x < x_crop + w_width; ++x) {
    for (int y = y_crop; y < y_crop + g_height; ++y) {
        map[x][y] = PlantType.symbol();
    }   
}
```

Some additional notes:

- You might want to consider adding checks for the parameters `x_crop` and `y_crop` in order to stay within the map's bounds
- Make the map indexing in your code consistent, in the loops you are indexing it by `map[x][y]` but the parameter declaration `char map[MAPL][MAPW]` suggests that it should rather be indexed by `map[y][x]`